# create multi valued variable inside mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameter

I have two IN variables into my MYSQL stored procedure. I pass one into a select statement and the value is taken in a temporary variable which is passed to the second SQL statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `usp_mystoredproc`(IN sText varchar(25), IN myId int(21))
begin

set @myCid= ( SELECT tabId AS id                    
FROM            table1
WHERE           IFNULL(tabId , '') != '' and table1_id= myId);

SELECT  searchItem 
FROM    table2 
WHERE  searchItem LIKE CONCAT(sText , '%') and table2_id =  @myCid
LIMIT                   15 ;
END
```

Now the issue is, in the above stored procedure, @myCid gets multiple values and it fails.
I need to get all those ids and pass them to the second SQL. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join table1 and table2. Something like:

```
SELECT  t2.searchItem 
FROM    table2 as t2
JOIN    table1 as t1
    ON t1.tabid = t2.table2_id
WHERE   t2.searchItem LIKE CONCAT(sText , '%') 
  AND IFNULL(tabId , '') != '' and t1.table1_id= myId
LIMIT                   15 ;
```

Bottom line, you don't need the @myCid variable

Comment: Indeed!! I saw this and thought what was I thinking.. Many thanks Lennart

Comment: @lennart : if I don't want to use joins then how do I handle this

Comment: @MansiChaudari, ask a new question where you describe the reason that you dont want to use a join. Make a link to this question if it helps to understand your scemario